# Creating a changeset for SlickGrid to save data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, slickgrid

I am aware that SlickGrid will modify the array that is assigned to the dataset.  What I'm wondering is is whether there exists any extension libraries that can be used with SlickGrid in order to keep track of a changeset to send to the server when persisting.  My application will have a large amount of data, so I only want to submit modifications.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any extensions/libraries, but it's really easy to do that using the `onCellChange` event or, if you need more control, the `editCommandHandler`.  See https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Writing-custom-cell-editors (Intercepting cell edits) for more info.